# Reparse an ASTUnit with relative header include paths fails

Tags: c++, clang, libclang, libtooling

I'm using libclang's `LibTooling` to get code completion data from C++ source files. 
The ASTUnits are generated from a *compile_commands.json* file created via `CMake` with `Ninja` as the generator.

In the compiler invocation commands, there are relative header include paths (such as `-Ifoo -I../bar`).

To successfully generate a [`clang::ASTUnit`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html), I need to set [`clang::FileManager::FileSystemOptions::WorkingDir`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FileSystemOptions.html) to instruct clang on how to canonicalise the relative paths.

> Problem is, when calling [`clang::ASTUnit::Reparse()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html#a09b8751a8405da53d2fb0b030f836af9) on my ASTUnits, this value is
>   discarded and my `clang::DiagnosticConsumer` then reports missing header files.

As a workaround, I'm regenerating the ASTUnits from scratch instead of reparsing them when the sources changes.

---

### Questions:

**`Q1:`** Is this normal behavior ? For me it essencialy makes `Reparse` useless.
**`Q2:`** How to successfully reparse an ASTUnit with relative header include paths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow-up :** Using *Clang/LLVM 4.0.0*, it is not possible to reparse an ASTUnit which compiler invocation contains relative include paths.

Starting from 5.0.0 however, [`clang::ASTUnit::Reparse`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html#a09b8751a8405da53d2fb0b030f836af9) contains a third argument that allows to pass a [`clang::vfs::FileSystem`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1vfs_1_1FileSystem.html) object that can solve this problem.